# How to disable I-Beam cursor on Text Widgets

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to do some text adventure kind of game, and I'm using a text widget to display the text. When my cursor hovers over the text widget, it becomes an I-Beam cursor, probably because it wants to select it. The widget is disabled and flags are turned off.

How do I turn off the I-Beam cursor for a more enjoyable experience?

```
window=Tk()
window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
window.title("Text Adventure")

txt=Text(window, font=("Comic Sans", 44), bg="Black", fg="white", width=width-100, borderwidth=0, wrap=WORD, exportselection=0)
txt.tag_configure('center', justify='center')
txt.insert('end', text, 'center')
txt.config(state=DISABLED)
txt.pack()

answer=Entry(window, font=("Comic Sans", 20), bg="Black", fg="Red", borderwidth=0, disabledbackground="Black", disabledforeground="Red", exportselection=0)
answer.place(x=(width/2)-ewidth/2, width=ewidth, height=eheight, y=height-eheight*8)

txt.bindtags((str(txt), str(window), "all"))
answer.bindtags((str(answer), str(window), "all"))
```

Comment: There is a `cursor=` option, read [Tkinter.Text.config-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#Tkinter.Text.config-method)

Comment: Try setting `cursor=None`. From the [man page for cursors](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/cursors.htm): "The **none** cursor can be specified to eliminate the cursor". On Windows, there's also one named "no".

Comment: great answers; i heard about cursor, but i didnt know it worked on texts! Thanks everyone